# Slow Execution Time for Cassandra with DataStax C# Driver

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, cassandra

I've managed to setup a Cassandra cluster in Microsoft Azure. Currently the cluster contains 2 nodes on 2 VMs in Azure. I've been using OpsCenter to check the status of the cluster and everything seems promising. However I've created a simple C# test client for the cluster using the DataStax C# Driver to connect to the cluster which actually are working but REALLY REALLY slow.

```
static class SimpleClient
{
    private static Session _session;
    public static Session Session 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _session; 
        } 
    }

    private static Cluster _cluster;
    public static Cluster Cluster 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _cluster; 
        } 
    }

    public static void Connect(String node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + node);
        _cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint(node).Build();
        _session = _cluster.Connect();
        Metadata metadata = _cluster.Metadata;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to cluster: " + metadata.ClusterName.ToString());
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        _cluster.Shutdown();
    }

    public static void CreateTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating table with name test1");
        _session.Execute(" CREATE TABLE kstt.test1 ( identifier text PRIMARY KEY, name text ); ");
        Console.WriteLine("Table created with name test1");
    }

    public static void InsertToTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting data into test1");
        _session.Execute(" INSERT INTO kstt.test1 ( identifier, name ) VALUES ( '" + "hello" + "', '" + "man" + "' );");
        Console.WriteLine("Data inserted into test1");
    }

    public static void ReadFromTable(int times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading data from test1");
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            RowSet results = _session.Execute(" SELECT * FROM kstt.test1; ");
            foreach (CqlColumn cqlColumn in results.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Keyspace: " + cqlColumn.Keyspace + " # Table: " + cqlColumn.Table + " # Name: " + cqlColumn.Name); 
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Data was read from test1");
    }

    public static void DropTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dropping table test1");
        try
        {
            _session.Execute(" DROP TABLE kstt.test1; ");
        }
        catch { }
        Console.WriteLine("Dropped table test1");
    }
}
```

This code actually do work. But it's **extremly** slow, taking about 10 seconds to connect and about 10 more seconds to execute a query. I think that it have something to do with the Load Balancer built in Azure among with the cassandra.yaml settings.

I've also noticed that the cluster are returning 2 IPs. One that is the external ip of the cluster and the other is the internal ip of one specific node which of course is unreachable from outside.

**This is our setup:**

Load Balancer on Port 9042

Load Balancer on Port 9160

cassandra-node1 with external ip 66.55.44.33 with internal ip 33.44.33.44

cassandra-node2 with external ip 66.55.44.33 with internal ip 11.22.11.22

**Cassandra Yaml**

Listen address for cassandra-node1: 33.44.33.44
RPC address for cassandra-node1: 33.44.33.44

Listen address for cassandra-node2: 11.22.11.22
RPC address for cassandra-node2: 11.22.11.22

*Sometimes the program even ends up in a WriteTimeoutException when executing an query.*

Comment: What's your ping time to the Cassandra nodes from wherever you're running the code? 10 seconds is obviously unreasonable, and I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

While it's difficult to look into a performance issue based only on these details, here are a couple of questions/comments:

1. where is your client running from?
2. what's the ping time between the Cassandra nodes and also from the client machine to the C* nodes?
3. you actually don't need a load balancer on port 9042 as the driver will be able to do load balancing by itself.
4. normally you should see some improvement by using prepared statements

Comment: The client is running from my home network while the cluster is in Azure. I can't ping the Azure VMs so I really don't know the response time in that matter. What's wierd is that the code actually works but is really slooow.

Comment: Try setting up a client inside azure to rule out problems on the external interface.

Comment: You can ping the azure vm's by using psping and ping the endpoint ports you have exposed. Or you can setup a instance ip and ping that since it will point to the VM directly and not the cloud service itself.